# Build multiple buildvariants in one go (AndroidStudio)

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have lots of buildTypes (say 10) in my gradlescript configured.

```
buildTypes {
demo1 {
}
demo2 {
}
test1 {
}
test2 {
}
full{
}
}
```

Actually I have to select a buildtype and then build the apk one by one.

Is there a way to build all buildvariants to all apk's in one go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to build all your variants at once, you can open Cmd and run this command:

> gradlew assemble